# POST-Request doesn't get forwarded via http-proxy

Tags: javascript, express, proxy, reverse-proxy, http-proxy

I am trying to build a reverse-proxy server where the url has an id (?id=1) and the proxy server redirects to port 8000 + id!

So it works when i go to the right port directly, but when I use the proxy the browser-tab loads endlessly.

It also works with GET-Request, but POST-Request don't work!

This is my reversed-proxy:

```
const express = require(`express`);
const proxy = require(`http-proxy`);

const ps = proxy.createProxyServer();
const app = express();
app.listen(8000);

app.all(`*`, (req, res) => {
    if (req.query.id) {
        try { const id = parseInt(req.query.id);
            ps.web(req, res, { target: `${req.protocol}://${req.hostname}:${8000+id}` });
        } catch (err) { res.redirect(redirectUrl); }
    } else { res.redirect(redirectUrl); }
});


ps.on(`error`, (err, req, res) => {
    res.redirect(redirectUrl);
});
```

This is my website running on port 8001:

```
app.get(`*`, (req, res) => {
    res.render(`index`, {
        link: `?id=1`,
        name: `name`,
        value: `value`,
        text: `text`,
    });
});

app.post(`*`, (req, res) => {
    res.render(`index`, {
        link: `?id=1`,
        name: `name`,
        value: `value`,
        text: `text`,
    });
});
```

And this is my html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action={{link}} method="POST">
            <button name={{name}} value={{value}}>
                <h4> {{text}} </h4>
            </button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

By the way i am also using express-handlebars so the {{}} in the html is for that!

ty for any ideas :)